# How to access method of another component on button click in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a button component that when clicked, should call a method of another component which will increment a value shown to the user. However, when I try to set the button to call that method on click, I always get the error, "Cannot read property of 'incrementState' of undefined'. How can I call this method when the button is clicked?

```
class IncreaseDiceButton extends React.Component {
      render () {
          return (<button onClick={NumDice.incrementState}>
                      Increase Number Of Dice
                  </button>); 
      }
};
```

```
class NumDice extends React.Component
{ 

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {mystate: 1};
  }    

  incrementState = () =>{
    var myNewState = this.state.mystate +1;
    this.setState({mystate: myNewState});
  };

  decrementState= () =>{
    var myNewState = this.state.mystate -1;
    if(myNewState > 0){
      this.setState({mystate: myNewState});
    }
  }
  render () {
    return ( <h2>
               {this.state.mystate}
             </h2>
           );  
  }
};
```

Comment: You're likely going to actually need to pass the `incementDice` function as a prop through your component hierarchy. Can you update the sample code showing how these two components are connected?

Comment: So your current approach is kind of an anti-pattern in React. Components should rarely be directly calling functions in other components, there's meant to be a hierarchy. A standard fix for this kind of problem is lifting the state and its incrementing/decrementing functionality up into a common parent, and pass down the state/functions to the relevant component through props.

Comment: @Nick I guess I don't really have a hierarchy, this is as connected as they are. This is my first day learning react so still getting a feel for how everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you're going to want to "lift" state up to a common ancestor. I took your code below and lifted state to a common "App" ancestor.

```
class IncreaseDiceButton extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <button onClick={props.incrementState}>
        Increase Number Of Dice
      </button>
    );
  }
};
```

```
class NumDice extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return (
      <h2>
        {props.mystate}
      </h2>
    );  
  }
};
```

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = { mystate: 1 }; 
  }

  incrementState = () => {
    var myNewState = this.state.mystate +1;
    this.setState({mystate: myNewState});
  };

  decrementState = () => {
    var myNewState = this.state.mystate -1;
    if(myNewState > 0){
      this.setState({mystate: myNewState});
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NumDice mystate={this.state.mystate} />
      <IncreaseDiceButton incrementState={incrementState} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, so then to render it all out I would just need something like ```    ReactDOM.render(<div><App /></div>,document.querySelector("#numDice"));
``` EDIT: this still produces the "incrementState is not defined" Error

Comment: Sure, that could work if you're trying to put the react app in the `numDice` DOM element!

Answer (score 0):

What you have in mind is an anti-pattern in React. You should form a hierarchy, mount both components on the same screen, then lifting the state up.

To think about how to redesign, first ask yourself what are the usage for each and every React Component, the behaviour and so on, and try to simplify them as much as possible.

`NumDice` is a React Component that rendering the latest count, so we can refactor it into below

```js
class NumDice extends React.Component
{
  render () {
    return (
      <h2>
        {this.props.currentDice}
      </h2>
    );  
  }
};
```

And `IncreaseDiceButton` component is to increase the Dice right? So we can refactor into below

```js
class IncreaseDiceButton extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.increaseDice}>
        Increase Number Of Dice
      </button>
    ); 
  }
};
```

And we need a "parent" component to manage the state, and the function to update the state, so below is an example

```js
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {mystate: 1};
  }

  incrementState = () =>{
    var myNewState = this.state.mystate +1;
    this.setState({mystate: myNewState});
  };

  decrementState= () =>{
    var myNewState = this.state.mystate -1;
    if(myNewState > 0){
      this.setState({mystate: myNewState});
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <IncreaseDiceButton increaseDice={this.incrementState} />
        <NumDice currentDice={this.state.mystate} />
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

And to put all puzzles together, below will be the way to construct it

```js
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {mystate: 1};
  }

  incrementState = () =>{
    var myNewState = this.state.mystate +1;
    this.setState({mystate: myNewState});
  };

  decrementState= () =>{
    var myNewState = this.state.mystate -1;
    if(myNewState > 0){
      this.setState({mystate: myNewState});
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <IncreaseDiceButton increaseDice={this.incrementState} />
        <NumDice currentDice={this.state.mystate} />
      </>
    )
  }
}

class IncreaseDiceButton extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.increaseDice}>
        Increase Number Of Dice
      </button>
    ); 
  }
};
```

Please note on the usage on how to pass the function reference by `props`. If you're serious about React, you do have to master what `props` and `state` is. Welcome to React :)